# How to make flask-admin display using chinese?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I found from [changelog](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/) that from 1.0.6 flask-admin begins to support chinese language. But after i checked through the document, i still don't get how to do it.

I want the menu displayed using chinese.

Comment: Do you see next example: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/babel/simple.py?

Comment: Thanks, i did it when check this example again. cool.